# Reprojecting to same srs shifting the layer

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr

I am using ogr2ogr to reproject a shapefile. Here is what I have done.

1. I have a shapefile **A.shp**. I used the following command to create **B.shp**:
   `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:3857 B.shp A.shp`
2. Now I reprojected **B.shp** again and created **C.shp** 
   `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:3857 C.shp B.shp`

Since B and C have same data and they are in same projection, I think they should completely overlap. However the do not. In the image bellow the Red one is A.shp and the other one is B.shp.

Is there a good reason why this can happen? This is happening to all the shapefiles not just this one.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might get a shift if the source CRS of the original shapefile is not given by an EPSG code, but a .prj file. These do not include datum sift parameters, and gdal tries to match the WKT information with its own EPSG database.

So I suggest to always add the `-s_srs` parameter for all ogr2ogr operations.

Comment: So, do you mean that the information in .prj file is not sufficient to do the reprojection?

Comment: If it is a CRS that has a datum shift (+towgs84 different from zero) in the EPSG code, it is not sufficient.